# C# Pong Game Paddle Movement via Microphone input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to build Pong Game with Microphone Input as controls for the paddles. the following part of the code (c#) is moving the paddle.

```
void Update () 
{
    loudness=GetAveragedVolume() * sensitivty;
    if (loudness>=8)
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=new Vector2(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y,4);
}
```

shouldn´t this code below do the job? however its not working

```
    else (loudness<=8) 
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=new Vector2(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y,-4);
    }
```

Its obviously an easy problem but im kinda stuck in here with this noob question
Thanks in advance

EDIT// what i want to do:

Move the paddle up when the microphone receives Sound and drop back down if there is no sound, just like an value from an visual amp.

Daniel

Comment: Tell us what is happening currently?

Comment: The clause after `else` must be a fully formed statement/block. You need to add an `if`... so `else if(loudness<8){...}`. Also, think about what happens if the value is ***exactly*** 8. Both conditionals will be satisfied (`loudness>=8` **and** `loudness<=8`) Is this really what you want to happen?

Comment: You should maybe replace the microphone input by something that can be tested more easily for now, and if that works reimplement the microphone.

Comment: `shouldn´t this code below do the job` you have to tell us, what's the job it should be doing? You obviously need to provide more context, would you expect to sit down at code that is foreign to you and understand it straight away? ` however its not working` in what way is it not working?

Comment: @spender What he wants is probably `if(loudness > 8) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @MarkusAppel - you're making assumptions until the question's clarified.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ To be fair, the code is very simple. Still he should explain what is currently happening and what he wants to happen.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ It is obvious what he wants to achieve. Also `probably`.

Comment: @MarkusAppel - fair enough, just trying to save everyone time and keep the focus on the OP sorting the question out. But you make a good point.

Comment: @Toilet Brush can you show us `GetAveragedVolume()` please? It does not seem to be part of Unity's API.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ you are right, I was thinking that spender 's comment might be more confusing than helpful for a newcomer.

Comment: @MarkusAppel the paddle is moving up but not down again. i know the "else" condition is wrong but i cant figure it out

Comment: @spender first i need to get a working prototype then there will be tweeking

Comment: @Toilet Brush delete the `(loudness<=8)`, so there is just the `else`. What happens now?

Comment: Does it only move up when you scream into the microphone or all the time?

Comment: @ToiletBrush - I suspect your problem lies outside of our analysis of your syntax here. As Markus has stated, it's simple code. Can you confirm `Update()` is being called again? Is it part of a loop?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ with now else if added it is working in some way but the paddle now goes straigt down left but it should go straigt down ...like an amplifyer

Comment: @ToiletBrush Change the `this.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity.y` to `this.GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity.x`, maybe that helps. As far as I remember Unity's vectors are `(x,y)`and `(x,y,z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `Update ()` is called correctly and `GetAveragedVolume()` returns meaningful values, it would have to look like this:

```
void Update () {

    loudness = GetAveragedVolume() * sensitivty;

    if (loudness > 8) {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, 4);
    }
    else {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, -4);
    }
}
```

Your mistakes:

- `else (...)` is invalid. Use `else if(...)`.
- You used `this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y` instead of `this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x` for the `x`-component of the two new vectors.

Some tips:

- Wether you use `>=` or `>` does not really matter for floating point numbers in most cases, and definitely not in your one.
- `else` is sufficient here. You don't need to check `else if (loudness <= 8)`, because if it isn't `> 8`, then it is always `<= 8`.
- Conventionally, you write `a = b;` / `a, b` and not `a=b;` / `a,b`, to make your code more readable.

I hope that works for you!